# How do I create a for loop to filter through different FDR values?

Tags: r

This is probably a really quick/simple fix but I am a Noob to R programming/programming in general. I am trying to create a for loop that runs the test multiple times with different FDR values (5,10,20). How do I make it run 3 times with different values and then produce 3 different datasets with names like... `atac.glmtop.males.opening.fdr5`, `atac.glmtop.males.opening.fdr10`, `atac.glmtop.males.opening.fdr20`? Also is there a way to make the `write.table` function work so that it exports files with the fdr5, fdr10, fdr20 in the name?

```r
fdr.nums = c("5","10","20")
fdr.nums.vector = c(5,10,20)

for (i in 1:length(fdr.list)){
  atac.glmtop.males.opening.fdr[i] <- topTags(
    atac.glmfit.males,
    n = nrow(atac.dge$counts),
    sort.by = "none",
    adjust.method = "fdr"
  )$table %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("peakco") %>%
  filter(logFC < 0) %>%
  filter(FDR < (fdr.vector[i]/100)) %>% 
  merge(.,annotated.atac.pbmc.narrow, by="peakco" ) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames("peakco")

  atac.glmtop.males.opening.fdr[i]

  write.table(
    atac.glmtop.males.fdr[i].opening[,c("chr", "start","end")], 
    file = paste0("~/Downloads/sexM.age.groupHO.fdr",i, ".opening.bed"), 
    sep = "\t",
    quote = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE
  )
  write.table(
    atac.glmtop.males.fdr[i].opening["GeneName"],
    file = "~/Downloads/sexM.age.groupHO.fdr"+ i + ".opening.GeneNames.txt",
    sep = "\t",
    quote = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bioinformatics.

Answer (score 2):

For loops in most languages can be done in a variety of ways. What you have currently coded, loops over values 1 to 3 by using

```r
for (i in 1:length(fdr.list)){
...
}
```

However, you probably want to use a different form and loop over each value in that vector using something more like:

```r
for (fdr in fdr.nums.vector){
...
}
```

This way you have convenient access to the FDR value in each loop via the `fdr` variable. Which you can then use in constructing your output filenames. Thus your code would become something like:

```r
fdr.nums.vector = c(5,10,20)

for (fdr in fdr.nums.vector){
  atac.glmtop.males.opening.fdr[fdr] <- topTags(
    atac.glmfit.males,
    n = nrow(atac.dge$counts),
    sort.by = "none",
    adjust.method = "fdr"
  )$table %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("peakco") %>%
  filter(logFC < 0) %>%
  filter(FDR < (fdr/100)) %>% 
  merge(.,annotated.atac.pbmc.narrow, by="peakco" ) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames("peakco")

  atac.glmtop.males.opening.fdr[fdr]

  write.table(
    atac.glmtop.males.fdr[fdr].opening[,c("chr", "start","end")], 
    file = paste0("~/Downloads/sexM.age.groupHO.fdr",fdr, ".opening.bed"), 
    sep = "\t",
    quote = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE
  )
  write.table(
    atac.glmtop.males.fdr[fdr].opening["GeneName"],
    file = "~/Downloads/sexM.age.groupHO.fdr"+ fdr + ".opening.GeneNames.txt",
    sep = "\t",
    quote = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE
  )
}
```

## Advancing From `for` Loops to `apply`

As a beginner, `for` loops seem quite logical and easy to understand. However, R has a more powerful way to achieve the same thing through what is called "vectorisation" using the `apply` function or one of it's relatives `lapply`, `sapply` etc. Once you have understood and mastered `for` loops, you should take a look at `apply`, especially if you ever need to do a `for` loop many times or you find yourself doing nested `for` loops. `R` is notoriously slow with `for` loops and `apply` will likely be many times faster (potentially orders of magnitude). Here are some links for when you are ready to advance from `for` loops to `vectorisation`.

- https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/
- https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/

Comment: You are right about vectorisation, however, apply is not vectorisation but uses for loops, see this for details: https://www.r-bloggers.com/vectorisation-is-your-best-friend-replacing-many-elements-in-a-character-vector/
or the document 'The R Inferno'.

Comment: “As a beginner, `for` loops seem quite logical and easy to understand” — this is really only true for people who are used to imperative programming. Properly taught, a functional-first approach is simpler for beginners. I strongly recommend skipping `for` loops in teaching and learning (or at least postponing them until *much* later in a course). Especially since, in R, they require all kinds of special explanations.